# How can I use ajax success data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, validation

It's form validate checker. How can i add ajax success message. after all validation I want to show success message like "**Your successfully signup**";

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#username').blur(function(e) {
        var username = $('#username').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            //url: 'http://localhost/stateway/user-signup/?username=' + username,
            url: 'http://localhost/blue_bucket/signup/?username=' + username,
            success: function (response) {
                $("#responseusername").html(response);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#email').blur(function(e) {
        var email = $('#email').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            //url: 'http://localhost/stateway/user-signup/?email=' + email,
            url: 'http://localhost/blue_bucket/signup/?email=' + email,
            success: function (response) {
                $("#responseemail").html(response);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$("#myForm").on("submit", function(){` ? I've never seen a signup form that works on `blur`, did you? You cannot match an `email` not knowing a password, and a user could fill-in an email first, right?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I think the idea is to check if the username and email entered are already taken, not to log the person in, or create an account for them

Comment: @sam000123 : what about suggested answers ? I believe your acceptance record is really questionable. Any of those past questions solved ? If so, it'd be best to mark them as solved, so that people know, and it's saved for the records. UV and accepting good answers is also part of the SO Q/A system.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You can use Javascript alert method or you can append success message to a div on DOM or something like.

and the thing is

When you are creating a `AJAX` Request if the request is made then it will go and hit your server side code. if the code successfully executed what you want to do. then `echo 'signup success'` and to show this message to your user simply just change this `$("#responseemail").html(response);` to this `alert(response)` and you are done.. ! I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

**IF** the idea is to check whether an email or username is already registered (ie: for a mailing list), then the following will help you.

> Keep in mind that you should **not** trust user's data from inputs, therefore, on the PHP part, in order to match form data against DB, you should **really** consider using [PPS : Prepared Parameterized Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This will help [Preventing SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

-> HTML + jQuery part (with jQuery library on top) :

-> you can check everything in the [jQuery manual -> 
jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
<div id="samplediv"></div> <!-- will handle answer -->

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {

$("#regbutton").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

          var email = $('#email').val();
          var username = $('#username').val();
          $.ajax({
           url: "register.php",
           method: "POST",
           data: "email="+email+"&username="+username,
           success: function(data){
             // if PHP response is OK we show it
             $("#samplediv").html(''+data'');
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
            }
          });
         });
});
</script>

<form action="#" id="form" method="post">
<p><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" /> email</p>
<p><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" /> username</p>
<input type="submit" id="regbutton" value="GO" />
</form>
```

-> On the PHP part (register.php):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];

// make all checking on user's data + match against DB here, if success ->

echo"Your successfully signup"; // else error : change message using PHP answer

?>
```